# code always prints incorrect username password

Tags: php, android, authentication

Hi i am using the following code to check whether the username and password is correct or not along with the php code.

The problem is that it always gives incorrect username or password even if i give the correct details.

```
String response = null;
try {
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.3.27/abc/check.php", postParameters);  //Enetr Your remote PHP,ASP, Servlet file link
String res=response.toString();
// res = res.trim();
res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
//error.setText(res);
error.setText(res);
if(res.equals("1")){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);           
startActivity(myIntent);

}
else
error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
```

This is  my php code.

```
<?php
$un=$_POST['username'];
$pw=$_POST['password'];
//connect to the db
$user = ‘root’;
$pswd = ‘root’;
$db = ‘mylogin’;
$conn = mysql_connect(‘localhost’, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
//run the query to search for the username and password the match
$query = “SELECT * FROM userpass WHERE login_id = ‘$un’ AND login_pass = ‘$pw’”;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(“Unable to verify user because : ” . mysql_error());
//this is where the actual verification happens
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)

echo 1;  // for correct login response
else
echo 0; // for incorrect login response
?>
```

Comment: try debugging with what result is coming `String res=response.toString();`

Comment: Does php code returns correct response?

Comment: Try to just echo 1 in php code. This helps you to find whether the problem is in the php code or the java code.

Comment: Sorry to be a party pooper but I really hope you aren't using that code publicly. Storing raw passwords and using un-sanitized mysql statements... That is just unacceptable.

Comment: thanks every1 ill try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to post values try like this

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",_username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",_pass));
try
{
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your url");
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   is = entity.getContent();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: if your username and password are correct, just check your php file coding is correct or not. especially check the query and if all are correct return correct result so that you can check with your android device

Comment: i have posted my php code also can yo check what wrong i am doing??